# Adding elevation, name and description in GeoJSON when converting DataFrame with Python

Tags: python, geojson, convert, pandas, data-frame

I have this working code, `data2kml()` function works ok, but `data2geojson()` is incomplete. How can I add the elevation, name and the description in the GeoJSON? I can't understand how `FeatureCollection` works.

Obs: I can't use GeoPandas because of some dependency conflicts.

```py
import json
import geojson
import simplekml
import pandas as pd

def data2kml(df):
    kml = simplekml.Kml()
    df.apply(lambda X: kml.newpoint(
            name=X["name"], 
            description=unicode(X["description"].decode('utf8')), 
            coords=[( X["long"], X["lat"], X["elev"])]
                                    )
            , axis=1)
    kml.save(path='map.kml')

def data2geojson(df):
    points = []
    df.apply(lambda X: points.append( (float(X["long"]), 
                                       float(X["lat"]))
                                    )
            , axis=1)
    with open('map.geojson', 'w') as fp:
        geojson.dump(geojson.MultiPoint(points), fp, sort_keys=True)


col = ['lat','long','elev','name','description']
data = [[-29.9953,-70.5867,760,'A','Place a'],
        [-30.1217,-70.4933,1250,'B','Place b'],
        [-30.0953,-70.5008,1185,'C','Place c']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=col)

data2kml(df)
data2geojson(df)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using what i learned from the answer of @gene this solution avoids the use of iterrows because [iterrows have performance issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-iterrows-have-performance-issues).

**Valid for Python 3.X**

```
import pandas as pd
import geojson

def data2geojson(df):
    features = []
    insert_features = lambda X: features.append(
            geojson.Feature(geometry=geojson.Point((X["long"],
                                                    X["lat"],
                                                    X["elev"])),
                            properties=dict(name=X["name"],
                                            description=X["description"])))
    df.apply(insert_features, axis=1)
    with open('map1.geojson', 'w', encoding='utf8') as fp:
        geojson.dump(geojson.FeatureCollection(features), fp, sort_keys=True, ensure_ascii=False)

col = ['lat','long','elev','name','description']
data = [[-29.9953,-70.5867,760,'A','Place ñ'],
        [-30.1217,-70.4933,1250,'B','Place b'],
        [-30.0953,-70.5008,1185,'C','Place c']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=col)

data2geojson(df)
```

**Valid for Python 2.X**

```
import pandas as pd
import geojson

def data2geojson(df):
    features = []
    df.apply(lambda X: features.append( 
            geojson.Feature(geometry=geojson.Point((X["long"], 
                                                    X["lat"], 
                                                    X["elev"])), 
                properties=dict(name=X["name"], 
                                description=unicode(X["description"].decode('utf8'))))
                                    )
            , axis=1)
    with open('map.geojson', 'w') as fp:
        geojson.dump(geojson.FeatureCollection(features), fp, sort_keys=True)

col = ['lat','long','elev','name','description']
data = [[-29.9953,-70.5867,760,'A','Place a'],
        [-30.1217,-70.4933,1250,'B','Place b'],
        [-30.0953,-70.5008,1185,'C','Place c']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=col)

data2geojson(df)
```

Answer (score 3):

Geoff Boeing  provides a solution in [Exporting Python Data to GeoJSON](http://geoffboeing.com/2015/10/exporting-python-data-geojson/) and 
[Convert a pandas dataframe to geojson for web-mapping (Jupyter notebook)](https://github.com/gboeing/urban-data-science/blob/3faf7e028d48cb03ddb999c5a910213c5384e7dc/17-Leaflet-Web-Mapping/leaflet-simple-demo/pandas-to-geojson.ipynb) for 2D coordinates and you can adapt his script for 3D coordinates

```
def df_to_geojson(df, properties, lat='lat', lon='long', z='elev'):
    geojson = {'type':'FeatureCollection', 'features':[]}
    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        feature = {'type':'Feature',
                   'properties':{},
                   'geometry':{'type':'Point','coordinates':[]}}
        feature['geometry']['coordinates'] = [row[lon],row[lat],row[z]]
        for prop in properties:
            feature['properties'][prop] = row[prop]
        geojson['features'].append(feature)
    return geojson

cols = ['name', 'description']
df_to_geojson(df, cols)
{'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'features': [{'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-70.5867, -29.9953, 760]}, 'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'name': 'A', 'description': 'Place a'}}, {'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-70.4933, -30.1217, 1250]}, 'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'name': 'B', 'description': 'Place b'}}, {'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-70.5008, -30.0953, 1185]}, 'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'name': 'C', 'description': 'Place c'}}]}
```

To explain the process with single features

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    print i,
    feature = {'type':'Feature','properties':{},'geometry':{'type':'Point','coordinates':[]}}
    feature['geometry']['coordinates'] = [row.long,row.lat,row.elev]
    for prop in cols:
        feature['properties'][prop] = row[prop]
    print feature

0 {'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-70.5867, -29.9953, 760]}, 'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'name': 'A', 'description': 'Place a'}}
1 {'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-70.4933, -30.1217, 1250]}, 'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'name': 'B', 'description': 'Place b'}}
2 {'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-70.5008, -30.0953, 1185]}, 'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'name': 'C', 'description': 'Place c'}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I finally learned the internal structure of the geojson format. With this knowledge i'm going to publish a solution that avoid the use of iterrows because [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-iterrows-have-performance-issues).

Answer (score 2):

For Python 3.6 users, this works for me:

> where df = yourdataframe,
>         properties are the usefull_columns, lat='latitude', lng='longitude'

The usefull_columns come from the original dataframe

I've added some testing points

```
# create the function
def df_to_geojson(df, properties, lat='latitude', lng='longitude'):
    """
    Turn a dataframe containing point data into a geojson formatted python dictionary

    df : the dataframe to convert to geojson
    properties : a list of columns in the dataframe to turn into geojson feature properties
    lat : the name of the column in the dataframe that contains latitude data
    lng : the name of the column in the dataframe that contains longitude data
    """

    # create a new python dict to contain our geojson data, using geojson format
    geojson = {'type':'FeatureCollection', 'features':[]}

    # loop through each row in the dataframe and convert each row to geojson format
    # x is the equivalent of the row, df.iterrows converts the dataframe in to a pd.series object
    # the x is a counter and has no influence
    for x, row in df.iterrows():

        feature = {'type':'Feature',
                   'properties':{},
                   'geometry':{'type':'Point',
                               'coordinates':[]}}

        # fill in the coordinates
        feature['geometry']['coordinates'] = [float(row.lng),float(row.lat)]

        # be aware that the dataframe is a pd.series
        #print('rowitem converts to ndarray(numpy) :\n ', row)
        # convert the array to a pandas.serie
        geo_props = pd.Series(row)

        # for each column, get the value and add it as a new feature property
        # prop determines the list from the properties
        for prop in properties:

            #loop over the items to convert to string elements

            #convert to string
            if type(geo_props[prop]) == float:
                #print('ok')
                geo_props[prop] = str(int(geo_props[prop]))

            # now create a json format, here we have to make the dict properties
            feature['properties'][prop] = geo_props[prop]

        # add this feature (aka, converted dataframe row) to the list of features inside our dict
        geojson['features'].append(feature)
    return geojson
```

Comment: Please remember to indent your code so it is formatted correctly. The `{}` button does this for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code:

```
def return_geojson(df, latlng):
    d = dict(type="FeatureCollection",features=[])

    for ind,row in df.fillna('').iterrows():
        p = row.drop(latlng).to_dict()
        g = dict(type="Point",coordinates=list(row[latlng])[::-1])
        f = dict(type="Feature", properties=p, geometry=g)
        d['features'].append(f)

    return d

with open('map.geojson','w') as f:
    json.dump(return_geojson(df,['lat','lon']),f)
```