# Convert raster to CSV with lat, lon, and value columns

Tags: python, gdal, data, coordinates, rioxarray

I'm looking for a process to convert ASCII gridded data (in this case 60min/1 degree gridded ASCII population data (GPW) from SEDAC: https://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/set/gpw-v4-population-count-adjusted-to-2015-unwpp-country-totals-rev11/data-download) to a CSV with three columns: lon, lat, and value using open source tools.

This is the data header:

```
ncols         360
nrows         180
xllcorner     -180
yllcorner     -90
cellsize      1.0000000000001
NODATA_value  -9999
```

so the data is structured as space-separated values, with each value occupying a position within 360 columns and 180 rows that represents its coordinates via that position:

```
-9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 0.000936705 0.002529013 0.001377391 0.001723122 0.0004472999 ...
```

I only want to include positive values in the lon/lat CSV.

I've been using GDAL for other tasks and have been looking in the documentation, but I'm not seeing this type of data manipulation in its scope.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this with [rioxarray](https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray):

Note: I used `data` for the column name as `values` is a pandas specific attribute.

```py
import rioxarray
import pandas

rds = rioxarray.open_rasterio(
    "gpw_v4_population_count_adjusted_to_2015_unwpp_country_totals_rev11_2020_1_deg.tif",
)
rds = rds.squeeze().drop("spatial_ref").drop("band")
rds.name = "data"
df = rds.to_dataframe().reset_index()
df[df.data>=0.0].to_csv("out.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: This solution backtracked on my process a bit by using the GeoTiff downloaded from SEDAC instead of the ASCII file. It's a great solution...much better than the brute force python method I was writing for the ASCII file. I wonder if I should change the title of the question to make it more general so others can find it.

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked - it should work the same with an ASCII file.

Comment: Title could be: Convert raster to CSV with lat, lon, and value columns

Comment: Will rioxarray translate between raster and geojson point features as well? I didn't see that in the documentation. On a lark I tried `df[df.data>0.0].to_geojson("out.geojson", index=False)` (didn't work).

Comment: This may help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220997/pandas-to-geojson-multiples-points-features-with-python

Comment: There's also geopandas: https://geopandas.org/gallery/create_geopandas_from_pandas.html#creating-a-geodataframe-from-a-dataframe-with-coordinates

Comment: Then, to geojson: https://geopandas.org/io.html#writing-spatial-data

Comment: Wow! super helpful, certainly saved me couple of days

Answer (score 3):

Even easier using GDAL from the command line, nothing to install!

1. Create a text file with your longitudes and latitudes, call it xy.txt:

```
-7, 41
-0.5, 51.4
```

2. Create the header of your shiny CSV file

```bsh
echo Longitude,Latitude,Pop > final.csv
```

3. Then pipe this through to [`gdallocationinfo`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdallocationinfo.html):

```bsh
cat xy.txt | tr -d , | gdallocationinfo -wgs84 -valonly \
           gpw_v4_population_count_rev11_2010_2pt5_min.tif > z.txt
```

3. Paste `xy.txt` and `z.txt` together and append to output `final.csv`

```bsh
paste -d,  xy.txt z.txt >> final.csv
```

You can then use `ogr2ogr` to convert the CSV to GeoJSON (see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/242805/2948))

```bsh
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON out.geojson final.csv \
         -oo X_POSSIBLE_NAMES=Longitude  \
         -oo Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES=Latitude \
         -oo KEEP_GEOM_COLUMNS=NO
```

From `ogrinfo -al out.geojson` I get:

```
INFO: Open of `out.geojson'
      using driver `GeoJSON' successful.

Layer name: final
Geometry: Point
Feature Count: 2
Extent: (-7.000000, 41.000000) - (-0.500000, 51.400000)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Pop: String (0.0)
OGRFeature(final):0
  Pop (String) = 4.11418008804321
  POINT (-7 41)

OGRFeature(final):1
  Pop (String) = 12097.869140625
  POINT (-0.5 51.4)
```