# Converting text file into GeoJSON using Python

Tags: python, geojson, convert, pandas, text

I'm trying to take in a *txt*-file and convert it into data for a GeoJSON dataset with these values.

I used this piece of code from this article:
[Pandas to GeoJSON (Multiples points + features) with Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220997/pandas-to-geojson-multiples-points-features-with-python)

```py
import geojson
import pandas as pd

def data2geojson(df):
    features = []
    insert_features = lambda X: features.append(
            geojson.Feature(geometry=geojson.LineString((X["long"],
                                                    X["lat"],
                                                    X["elev"])),
                            properties=dict(name=X["name"],
                                            description=X["description"])))
    df.apply(insert_features, axis=1)
    with open('map1.geojson', 'w', encoding='utf8') as fp:
        geojson.dump(geojson.FeatureCollection(features), fp, sort_keys=True, ensure_ascii=False,indent=4)

col = ['lat','long','elev','name','description']
data = [[-29.9953,-70.5867,760,'A','Place MNO'],
        [-30.1217,-70.4933,1250,'C','Place PQR'],
        [-30.0953,-70.5008,1185,'C','Place STU']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=col)

data2geojson(df)
```

However for data, I have points that are in the same line (hence why I am using `LineString` instead of `Point`) and they have unique `"ID"`s to be placed in the 'properties' section of the GeoJSON.

This is an example of the data in my *txt*-file

```
lat=1.3218368 ,long=103.9364834 ,A, Place BC
lat=1.3218821 ,long=103.9364744 ,A, Place BC
lat=1.3219285 ,long=103.9367017 ,A, Place BC
lat=1.321643 ,long=103.9364707 ,A, Place BC
lat=1.3216271 ,long=103.9363887 ,A, Place BC
lat=1.3235089 ,long=103.9344606 ,A, Place BC
lat=1.3237205 ,long=103.9355026 ,A, Place BC
lat=1.3217046 ,long=103.934106 ,A, Place BC
lat=1.3203204 ,long=103.9366324 ,B, Place AC
lat=1.3206557 ,long=103.9373536 ,B, Place AC
lat=1.3206271 ,long=103.9374192 ,B, Place AC
lat=1.3205511 ,long=103.9371742 ,B, Place AC
lat=1.3206044 ,long=103.9375056 ,B, Place AC
lat=1.3207561 ,long=103.9371863 ,B, Place AC
lat=1.3204307 ,long=103.9368537 ,B, Place AC
lat=1.3204877 ,long=103.9368389 ,B, Place AC
lat=1.3205465 ,long=103.9368269 ,B, Place AC
lat=1.320612 ,long=103.9368246 ,B, Place AC
lat=1.3207378 ,long=103.9371016 ,B, Place AC
lat=1.3207702 ,long=103.9370846 ,B, Place AC
```

How should I go about with taking in this txt as the input for the function's `data` array and grouping them according to the `name` e.g. A or B, regardless of `description` as `LineString` have more than 1 point attached to each object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using geopandas is a more convenient way to create GeoJSON.
Once you convert your txt to coordinates, you need to do some preliminary work.
This is the process of handling str in pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

#handling txt
#remove 'lat=' and 'long=' then type change from object to float to make point.
df = pd.read_csv('path_your_txt', header=None, names = ['lat','long', 'name','description'])

df['lat'] = df['lat'].str.replace('lat=', '')
df['long'] = df['long'].str.replace('long=', '')

df['lat'] = df['lat'].astype(float)
df['long'] = df['long'].astype(float)

#make point geometry
df['geometry'] = df.apply(lambda row: Point(row['long'], row['lat']), axis=1) #long is X, lat is Y

#change df to gdf
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry = 'geometry', crs='EPSG:4326')  #epsg4326 is WGS84
```

Having created a gdf, you have now created a spatial data containing points and attribute data.

Now you only need one command to create GeoJSON.

```
gdf.to_file('path_and_filename.geojson', driver='GeoJSON')
```

As for grouping, what you need to do depends on the purpose of the grouping.
If you just want to count, use groupby.

```
gdf.groupby('name').size()
```

If what you want is to create a line, you need a slightly different approach.

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString
gdf_line = gdf.groupby(['name', 'description'])['geometry'].apply(lambda x: LineString(x.tolist()))
```

Comment: Thank you!!! for the 'low' word I am getting an undefined error for it. should I be importing another module? This is the error I get, "name 'low' is not defined"

Comment: @MeganDarcy WOW, I'm sorry. That's a typo in "row". I edited it.